# Каким образом перенести данные с одного TableVC к другому

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

Я новичок в `Swift` и у меня есть проблема. Имеется два `UITableViewController`, при нажатии на Cell осуществляется переход
на другой контроллер, где статично указаны соответствующие данные которые мне нужны:

`var arrayOFJumpForwardBack: [Int: [String: [String]]] = [1: ["Chapter": ["15 sec","30 sec","45 sec","60 sec"]]]`

`Cell` я создал при помощи Xib, в котором есть 2 `UIlabel`, один для имени, второй для показа соответствующих секунд при выборе их в `didSelectedRowAt` из второго контроллера. Могли бы вы подробно написать или объяснить, как я могу засетить секунды в xib при выборе их из второго контроллера?

Comment: Честно говоря я не до конца понял проблему. Где вы выбираете секунды и куда их надо засетить?

Comment: Если я правильно понял то вот что Вам надо: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-pass-data-between-two-view-controllers

Comment: Виталий , спасибо конечно за ссылку, очень познавательно, я прочитал все, я понял в чем проблема

Answer (score 0):

В `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` когда получаешь ячейку, ты можешь указать данные для отображения. Для каждой ячейке в свой ViewController в отдельных переменных (или массиве) храни значения что нужно отображать.
Когда тебе нужно поменять отображаемое значение, просто меняешь в нужном месте эти данные и обновляешь таблицу `UITableView.reloadData()`. Соотвественно ячейка перенастроится и покажет новое значение.

Как передать эти данные назад из 2го контроллера в 1й - тебе в комментарии скинули ссылку с примером. 
Вместо делегата можно использовать кложур для обратной связи - тут каждому уже что больше по душе.

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение!!